# Why i'm getting error on the Microsoft.DirectX.Direct3D.Device?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

The whole code is very long.
So i will add here only the relevant lines.

At the top of the form:

```
private Device D3Ddev = null;
```

Device is Microsoft.DirectX.Direct3D.Device

Then:

```
private Boolean InitializeDirectX()
        {

                DispMode = Manager.Adapters[Manager.Adapters.Default.Adapter].CurrentDisplayMode;
                D3Dpp = new PresentParameters();
                D3Dpp.BackBufferFormat = DispMode.Format;
                D3Dpp.PresentFlag = PresentFlag.LockableBackBuffer;

                D3Dpp.SwapEffect = SwapEffect.Discard;
                D3Dpp.PresentationInterval = PresentInterval.One; //wait for vertical sync. Synchronizes the painting with
                //monitor refresh rate for smoooth animation
                D3Dpp.Windowed = true; //the application has borders

            try
            {
                D3Ddev = new Device(Manager.Adapters.Default.Adapter, DeviceType.Hardware, pictureBox1.Handle,
                                                                           CreateFlags.SoftwareVertexProcessing, D3Dpp);
                D3Ddev.VertexFormat = CustomVertex.PositionColored.Format;
                D3Ddev.RenderState.Lighting = false;
                D3Ddev.RenderState.CullMode = Cull.CounterClockwise;

                backTexture = TextureLoader.FromStream(D3Ddev, mymem);
                scannedCloudsTexture = new Texture(D3Ddev, 512, 512, 1, Usage.Dynamic, Format.A8R8G8B8, Pool.Default);

                //sprite is used to draw the texture
                D3Dsprite = new Sprite(D3Ddev);

                return true;
            }
            catch
            {
                Logger.Write("error");
                return false;
            }
        }
```

The error is on the line:

```
D3Ddev.VertexFormat = CustomVertex.PositionColored.Format;
```

On the Format.

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   CS0012  The type 'IsConstModifier' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Microsoft.VisualC, Version=7.0.5000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.        DopplerEffect.cs    467 Active

Comment: The Managed DirectX library is very, very old and was discontinued just before .NET 2.0 shipped.  Microsoft no longer wanted to support it, that was not because it was a great library.  You are missing a dependency, goes back to Visual Studio 2002.  Get ahead with the open source alternatives for this library, like SharpDX and SlimDX.

Answer (score 4):

As it states you need to add the reference to the assembly 'Microsoft.VisualC'.

Search somewhere in "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Microsoft.VisualC.dll"